# How do I add an icon url to my Nuget package using Visual Studio for Mac

Tags: nuget, azure-pipelines, visual-studio-mac, azure-artifacts, nuget-spec

I set the Icon Url using the nuget properties of my .csproj in Visual Studio for Mac. However, when I deploy it to Azure Artifacts (which is like nuget.org), no image icon appears. I am also deploying using Azure Pipelines. I've also tried clearing my cache but no success.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Azure Artifacts web UI doesn't display package icons at this time.

After a recent server-side change, icons specified via IconUrl should now appear in clients that support them (such as regular Visual Studio; not sure about VS for Mac).

Comment: Wow. You're right. Thank you. https://i.imgur.com/PbxzW6T.png

Comment: Does this mean that I should be seeing icons in the NuGet browser in VS for packages I published to Azure Artifacts that include <PackageIconUrl>https://i.imgur.com/something.png</PackageIconUrl> in the CSPROJ?  I ask because I'm not seeing them.  Have I misunderstood?